# Error in text mining: "replacement has length zero" & "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

Tags: r, string, tm

I was trying to extract multi-words from text using for loop.

The following line of code gives me an error which says `replacement has length zero` and `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`. To make it clear my question, consider the following situation.

```
library(tm)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
mydata<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), 
          text=c("This is text mining exercise","Text analysis is bit confusing","Hint on this text 
          analysis?")) 
multiwords<-c("text","analysis","bit confusing")
txt<- freq<- list() 
for(i in 1:length(mydata$id)){ 
    txt[i]<-str_extract_all(mydata[i,], paste0(multiwords,collapse = "|")) freq[i]<-table(txt[i])
}
```

Note that every terms in `multiwords` does not necessarily appear at each iteration.

Comment: `str_extract_al` is vectorized  for both 'string', and patterns. If the patterns are for the corresponding rows, then you can just use `str_extract_all(mydata$text, multiwords)` and if not `str_extract_all(mydata$text,  str_c(multiwords, collapse="|"))`

Comment: @akrun Yeah, I'm looking for the same pattern for each row.  But the indicated code is not working for me.

Comment: Based on your example, it is running for me and it is giving a list output.  Not sure what you meant by `not working for me`

Comment: @akrun I'm getting the same error. I don't know what mistake I did. Would you kindly put your code, if possible?

Comment: I get `str_extract_all(mydata$text, str_c(multiwords, collapse="|"))#
[[1]]
[1] "text"

[[2]]
[1] "analysis"      "bit confusing"

[[3]]
[1] "text"     "analysis"`

Comment: It is also possible that version difference of package can be the source of error

Comment: Yes, you're right. But  `table(str_extract_all(mydata$text, str_c(multiwords, collapse="|")))` gives you an error.

Comment: please check my solution posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need the `table` on the entire extracted elements, use `str_extract_all` on the 'text' column after pasteing the 'multiwords' as `pattern`, then `unlist` the `list` and get the `table`

```
library(stringr)
lst1 <- str_extract_all(mydata$text, str_c(multiwords, collapse="|"))
table(unlist(lst1))
#    analysis bit confusing          text 
#           2             1             2
```

If we need to apply `table` on each element of `list`

```
lapply(lst1, table)
#[[1]]

#text 
#   1 

#[[2]]

#     analysis bit confusing 
#            1             1 

#[[3]]

#analysis     text 
#       1        1
```

Comment: Great. It's super nice now!